# Removing default mysql on Slackware 13

Tags: linux, mysql, uninstall, slackware

I was playing around the default mysql that comes with Slackware 13, and I think I broke it somehow. I don't want to fix it, I'd like to start from scratch, building from source and everything, but first I have to remove this broken installation. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe on slackware you use removepkg to uninstall a package

Comment: while looking up about removepkg I found out about pkgtools, used it to uninstall. thanks!